# codeigniter input tag attribute

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can anyone explain, how this cat array is getting the id and name?

```
foreach ($all_categories as $menu) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" id="cat_<?php echo $menu->id; ?>" value="<?php echo     $menu->id.'_'.$menu->name; ?>" name="cat[]">
..
..
}
```

and i can get the id and name in controller,by using like below. It is working totally fine. My question is, how `id` went to `cat array` in position 0,and name position 1?

```
$res_arr=explode('_',$value);
$cat_id=$res_arr[0];
$cat_name=$res_arr[1];
```

Comment: You are splitting the value by `_`. So if it is `1_aaa` then `$res_arr[0]` will be `1` & $res_arr[1] will be `aaa`.

Answer (score 0):

The `explode` function returns an `array` either it finds the `delimiter` or not. You gave a `string` to `explode` and asked it to `split` the `string` wherever it sees `'_'`. So in your case there was only one `'_'` and `explode` sliced the `string` into two pieces and placed them in an `array` respectively at `[0]` and `[1]`.

**Edit:**

```
<?php
foreach ($all_categories as $menu) {
print "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"cat_".$menu->id."\" value=\"".$menu->id."_".$menu->name."\" name=\"cat[]\"/>";
}
?>
```

php short tag is not recommended [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Comment: 1. id="cat_<?php echo $menu->id; ?>, why i can't write like this,without echo? id="cat_  $menu->id???

2.name="cat[]", is it work like that? for first iteration of this loop, name is cat[0],for 2nd iteration of loop,name is cat[0] and so on ??

Comment: 1. if you want to write without `echo`, you have two choices; either use `id="cat_<?=$menu->id?>"` or do not break the php tag and print everything. Let me edit the answer for this one.
2. name="cat[]" does not work like this here. It tells the browser that there are more elements with the same name and send them as an array when sending form.